# Change body_class() PAGE to HOME

Tags: php, body-class

I have a static Page Template with new updated post and i need change the body class page to home, the actualy class is:

```
page page-id-2 page-template page-template-page-update page-template-page-update-php logged-in not-touch-device
```

and i need replace page with home like:

```
**home** page-id-2 page-template page-template-page-update page-template-page-update-php logged-in not-touch-device
```

i have tried with:

```
<body <?php echo str_replace("page", "home", body_class()); ?> itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">
```

but the result is always page, i need this change only on this page and not on entry.

Comment: Why do you need to change that? Sounds like an A/B problem.

Comment: Theme support my custom function only if class is HOME, and change 200 lines of css is not possibile for me.

Comment: 200 lines? Wtf are you talking about? CSS is easy find and replace with a NEW CLASS NAME (better yet, use sass or less compiles). This question makes no sense. No one tries to `preg_replace` a class do they???!!!?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'body_class', 'alter_body_class', 20, 2 );
function alter_body_class( $classes ) {
    foreach( $classes as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value === 'page' ) {
            unset( $classes[ $key ] );
        }
    }
    return array_merge( $classes, array( 'home' ) );
}
?>
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? There's a great opportunity here to introduce the `body_class` filter, and what it does. Instead it's just copypasta, there's easy upvotes to be had here!

Comment: Cool, you showed how to put a cart before a horse.